# Xcode 11 crashes when opening the project

Tags: crash, xcode11

I downloaded new Xcode 11 today and when I am trying to open my project, Xcode will always crash.
Does anyone else experience this problem ? I have provided part of crash log. It's IDE related problem, but I would be really glad, someone has a solution to this.

```
Crashed Thread:        25  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEProvisioningMechanic _executeNextRepairIfNeeded]_block_invoke

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11A420a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-14936/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/Mechanic/IDEProvisioningRepairStepGenerator.m:252
Details:  Didn't find a single primary certificate type from {(
)}
Object:   <IDEProvisioningRepairStepGenerator_Automatic: 0x7fdc55061ef0>
Method:   -_evaluateCertificatesWithSession:context:repairable:steps:userAction:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fdc44944ca0>{number = 20, name = (null)}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[IDEProvisioningRepairStepGenerator_Automatic _evaluateCertificatesWithSession:context:repairable:steps:userAction:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  4   -[IDEProvisioningRepairStepGenerator_Automatic stepsWithSession:context:userAction:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  5   -[IDEProvisioningRepair execute] (in IDEFoundation)
  6   __53-[IDEProvisioningMechanic _executeNextRepairIfNeeded]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
  7   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
  8   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  9   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14   _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 16   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

I have deleted caches in library, derivated data, even disabled automatic signing, but none of these work.

**UPDATE**

Project can be opened, when I logout from developer account, otherwise, this crash always occurs.

Comment: Some kind of signing issue. Replacing automatic signing with manual as James suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for a day on older Xcode, suddenly error popped out, that code signing in our test target is wrong, so I just removed team and added it again.

Comment: How did you remove your team when you can't open the project?

Comment: I installed Xcode 10, which doesn't crash, changed wrong team in target (in out case, test target) and then it worked with Xcode 11.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same crash on XCode 11.3.1. I went on to "Show package contents" of the ".xcworkspace" workspace directory and deleted "xcuserdata" folder. This resolved the crash for me.

Comment: Works for me at first time, but crash next time when I am signing my target.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions works for me, including all solution [this discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123204) in Apple Developer Forums. Someone suggest you delete all `xcuserdata` in `*.xcworkspace` folder; Someone suggests you create a new `*.xcworkspace` from you `xcodeproj`. However, those are not workarounds for me.

It seems a signing issues on my project, but I cannot open my project to reset the provisions method. So I modify the `project.pbxproj` file located in `*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. Replace ALL:

```
ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
```

to

```
ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
```

Then open the project to uncheck **automatically manage signing** in Signing & Capabilities option. Then when I sign again manually, problem solved.

I still don't know why this error comes out, but it just crashes every time I sign my **UITest** target. Hope someone can explain to me.

Comment: I think you are having same problem as we had. Do you have multiple teams for signing ? In our case, we had 2 teams with very similiar name and one was used for testing target and another for application target and this caused the crash. Also XCode's stack trace does not contain information, whats wrong. You can request technical support at [apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/). Hopefully, they can figure it out, but I can't help any further.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the .xcworkspace from your project. then 
from terminal pod install. This is how solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was occurring with me for one project. I just delete .workspace file and reinstall pods so .workspace file is generated. Now i am able to open this project and Xcode is not crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. if you are using the pod.
Delete .xcworkspace file and pod update
2. If there is any xib file that is not supported or corrupted.
copy that xib outside and remove from the physical folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting:

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace ASSERTIOND, Code 0xd00d2bad
```

Tried restarting Xcode, the computer, deleting xcworkspace, but nothing worked.

Finally deleting Derived Data worked. This is because I'm testing Xcode extensions (12.4) and had an error in my `XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey` dictionary. I was storing an integer for `.identifierKey` instead of a String.

Since I was actively developing the extension, I [had to delete Derived Data to remove the extension](https://github.com/cyanzhong/xTextHandler/issues/2#issuecomment-247842124).